# How to use ContactsContract as a Table in ContentProvider

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

While setting the table via`setTable` method in the `query` method of my `ContentProvider`, I am doing something like this :

```
queryBuilder.settable(getTable());
```

where my **`getTable()`** is :

```
private String  gettable(){
    String table;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(Table_1_Name);
    sb.append(" LEFT JOIN ");
    sb.append(Table_1_Name);
    sb.append(" ON (");
    sb.append(Table_1_Name.ID);
    sb.append(" = ");
    sb.append(Table_1_Name.ID);
    sb.append(")");
    table = sb.toString();
    return table;
}
```

Now instead of using **`Table_2_Name`** , i need to use **`ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone`** table. How can i do this. I need to filter some records in my where clause but first i dnt know how to use  `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone` as a Table.